# ASP.NET Identity VS Самописная система авторизации

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth2, asp.net-identity-2

Может показаться что это очень "холиварный" вопрос, но я всё же задам его.

Начинал писать свою систему ещё тогда, когда был в моде **ASP.NET Membership**. Ну естественно, гибкости мне далеко не хватало и я решил писать свою систему авторизации, не опираясь на какие-то устоявшиеся в те времена принципы разработки *авторизационных/аутентификационных* систем. Что примерно из себя напоминает система сейчас:

- Отдельный контекст (мало ли что в жизни бывает);
- CodeFirst - реализация;
- Хранение токена сессии в кукисах и сравнение его с токеном в отдельной таблице в БД.
- Авторизационные фильтры типа (`[IdentityFilter("admin", "user", "manager")]`) и типа (`[IdentityFilter(RolesEnum.Manager)]`). На выбор ;)
- Репозиторий.
- Авторизационная информация получается в фильтре и далее гуляет в HttpContext`e.
- Ну и много других мелочей.

Так вот, как бы работает быстро, но что то подсказывает мне, что можно ещё быстрее.

Собственно хотелось узнать, какие преимущества может нести для меня **Identity** и целесообразно ли его использование в "реальном продакшне", или же это интерфейс для новичков, и для тех, кто не хочет парится.

Ведь в моём коде для меня нет никаких ограничений, а вот в **Identity** ограничения всё таки есть, хотя бы то же самое именование таблиц и полей по умолчанию.

P.S. Прошу очень ***развёрнутый***, и тем более ***аргументированный*** ответ. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Имена таблиц могут быть изменены при помощи fluent api.

Comment: @Bald ну с этим хорошо, понял. Как быть с начальной структурой таблиц, связей и полей. Можно ли отказаться от claims?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Membership** забыл как страшный сон, перешел на **Identity**:

- Нужна простая авторизация без лишней возни? - пожалуйста. Добавил подсистему и забыл.
- Нужно использовать Claims? - пожалуйста. Не нужно? - можно добавить в любой момент, а до тех пор хранить все основной таблице. А Claims так и будет ждать своего часа.
- Нужно добавить авторизацию через соцсети? - пожалуйста.
- Не нравятся именование полей или самой таблицы? - можно все переименовать.
- Нужно добавить новое поле? - пожалуйста. Автоматическая миграция, ничего не нужно удалять или бэкапить.
- Необходима двухфакторная аутентификация с подтверждением по смс или электронной почте? - Всё есть, просто добавить необходимые службы.
- Дополнительные требования к логинам и паролям? - орудия пыток на выбор:

  ```
  AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames,
  RequireUniqueEmail
  // -------------------
  RequiredLength = 6,
  RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
  RequireDigit = false,
  RequireLowercase = false,
  RequireUppercase = false
  ```

и т.д. и т.п.

Проще в студии загрузить готовый шаблон и поковырять его пару вечерков, чтобы точно убедиться подходит ли **Identity** для своих нужд.
Для загрузки рабочего примера с комментариями в консоли пишем «Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre»

## Update

- Если нужно простое, гибкое, функциональное и готовое решение - **Asp.net Identity** подойдет. Все в коробке.
- Если необходимо реализовывать сложные сценарии: глубокие политики безопасности, одновременная аутентификация по Active Directory, сертификатам, токенам, онлайн формам (как на всех сайтах), то советую обратить внимание на **Windows Identity Foundation**. Придется несколько попотеть.

Comment: Не использовал _ASP.Net Identity_, но тема авторизации в общем меня интересует. Например, сейчас делаю механизм авторизации основанный на _Claims_. Поясните пожалуйста фразу "если не _Claims_, то можно хранить всё в основной таблице". Если приблизительно и упрощенно, то какой структуры имеется ввиду таблица? Роли-действия-permissionы?

Comment: Поставлю "ОТВЕТ", но интересно послушать ещё мнения!

Comment: Структура таблицы может быть любой. На хабре есть хорошая статья "ASP.NET 5 Identity 3 и новый инструментарий аутентификации/авторизации", возможно часть технических вопросов отпадет

Comment: @AndreyK., под хранением в основной таблице я имел ввиду принцип лени, данный подход я не рекомендую: если не хочется возится и разбираться с настройкой Claims, то в профиль пользователя можно добавить поля-флаги, отвечающие за доступ к конкретным частям сайта. Просто добавив одну строчку в сущность пользователя мы получим способ влиять на поведение системы проверяя наличие флага. Повторюсь, так не следует делать.

Comment: @Ice2burn Мне в голову приходит только одно: это создать таблицу ролей, таблицу привелегий и задать ролям привелегии. Или как вариант вешать на контроллеры в целом или на отдельные методы атрибут с доступными ролями, собственно как у меня и было сделано, за 2 года ни одного неудобного случая в использовании не нашлось!

Comment: @gromanev в Identity это все уже есть, вот только делается несколько иначе: привилегии задаются не просто ролям, а целым группам или пользователям. Так можно будет запретить доступ к контенту выборочным пользователям, например, с возрастом менее 18 лет и с 23.00 до 6.00 без необходимости добавления новых ролей.

Comment: @Ice2burn ого, это всё уже есть из коробки?

Comment: @gromanev мы говорим об авторизации, так что из коробки предлагается role-based. Claims изначально есть и служат для быстрого получения дополнительных данных о пользователе, например фио или возраста. При желании, можно сделать claim-based авторизацию, где будут проверяться поля из claims: те же фио и возраст. Их придется задавать для каждого пользователя. Поработав напильничком, можно сделать уже group-based-permissions. Все есть, все можно изменить и переопределить, пользуйтесь. Туториалов полно.

Answer (score 2):

Холивар полнейшей -)

Добавлю к ответу от товарища @Ice2burn - авторизация по клеймам возможна и достаточно проста в написании. Я написал подобное и уже года полтора в продакшне использую с большим успехом. Прототип можно поковырять [здесь](https://github.com/trailmax/ClaimsAuthorisation).

Identity состоит на самом деле из нескольких пакетов:

- `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` - в основном интерфейсы и базовые имплементации классов которые не относятся к хранению данных
- `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` - имплементации классов которые относятся к хранению данных. Здесь все заточенно под EF, но все имплементации могут быть замененны на кастомное хранилище. Я видел пакеты которые позволяют хранить информацю о юзерах использую NHibernate или в RavenDb или Azure Tables. Так что хранилище может быть замененно без проблем.
- `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` - адаптер для использования OWIN и создания кукисов через OWIN. В принципе тоже можно заменить, но не могу придумать зачем это менять.

Claims - весьма удобная вещь. Все клеймы которые добавленны в запись юзера попадают в authentication куки и их оттуда можно достать без проблем. Их можно не использовать, но потратить полчаса на понимание как они работают и отказаться будет невозможно -). Когда создается печенка для входа на сайт, все пользователькие роли на самом деле записываются в куку как клеймы. Система потом достает из куки все клеймы с названием `Role`. То есть хочешь-не хочешь а клеймы используются по дефолту. Можно даже сказать что роли это по сути отдельный класс клеймов.

Еще одна очень удобная вещь в Identity это SecurityStamp - GUID на записи пользователя. Если это поле меняется в базе, то сбрасываются все пользователькие куки и надо логиниться по-новой. Так можно легко предотвращать двух людей которые логинятся с разных компов под одним аккаунтом - полезно когда бизнес модель предполагает оплату по количеству аккаунтов.