# Как включить Identity Manager в проекте ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Когда создавал проект, выбрал способ авторизации Organizational Accounts - Single Organization. По умолчанию Identity Manager там не используется, таблиц AspNetUser, AspNetRoles и тому подобных не создалось. Сейчас появилась необходимость разграничить роли, и тип авторизации менять уже поздно. Можно ли как-то включить Identity Manager, записать всех авторизовавшихся пользователей в БД и раздать им роли?

Comment: следует обратить внимание на вот этот вопрос на [so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31963828/5610621). рекомендую предварительно сделать backup проекта.

Comment: @Bald а такой способ подойдет для текущей авторизации? Она ведь сквозная была, как пользователь будет записываться в базу? И я так понимаю, контекст базы там новый заводится, следовательно таблицы пересоздадутся?

Comment: не обязательно создавать новый *контекст*, можно изменить существующий, т.е. надо будет сделать миграцию, на основании которой будут *добавлены* необходимые таблицы. пользователей надо будет создать. а вообще я бы наверно *создал* новый проект с необходимым типом авторизации, перенес туда существующий функционал, а данные перенес бы средствами `sql` запросов

Comment: @Bald все это выглядит так, что кажется, будто проще будет самому создать таблицу пользователей и таблицу ролей и написать свои AuthorizationAttribute

Comment: [ASP.NET Identity VS Самописная система авторизации](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/508044/179270). можно то оно можно но нужно ли?

Comment: @Bald ну все описанные там преимущества теряются при использовании авторизации через AD. Видимо поэтому по умолчанию Identity  Manager даже не подключается

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42643/discussion-between-bald-and--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете SSO - то роли в таких случаях принято выдавать на стороне STS. Ищите нужные настройки на той стороне, где пользователь вводит свой логин и пароль.

Если вы используете авторизацию через AD - то обычно назначение ролей пользователю сводится к добавлению его в специальную группу на стороне контроллера домена.

Возможно, придется написать свой атрибут для проверки ролей, чтобы можно было настраивать имя проверяемой роли в конфиге.